# Block for stdin in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stdin, blocking

**Short explanation:**

I'm attempting to write a simple game in `Node.js` that needs to wait for user input every turn. How do I `avoid callback` hell (e.g. messy code) internal to a turn loop where each turn loop iteration needs to block and wait for input from stdin?

**Long explanation:**

All the explanations I have read on StackOverflow when someone asks about blocking for `stdin` input seem to be "that's not what Node.js is about!"

I understand that Node.js is designed to be non-blocking and I also understand why. However I feel that it has me stuck between a rock and a hard place on how to solve this. I feel like I have three options:

1. Find a way to block for stdin and retain my while loop
2. Ditch the while loop and instead recursively call a method (like nextTurn) whenever the previous turn ends.
3. Ditch the while loop and instead use setTimeout(0, ...) or something similar to call a method (like nextTurn) whenever a turn ends.

With option (1) I am going against Node.js principles of non-blocking IO.
With option (2) I will eventually reach a stack overflow as each call adds another turn to the call stack.
With option (3) my code ends up being a mess to follow.

Internal to Node.js there are default functions that are marked **Sync (e.g. see the fs library or the sleep function) and I'm wondering why there is no Sync method for getting user input? And if I were to write something similar to `fs.readSync` how would I go about doing it and still follow best practices?

Comment: I would use events for that: http://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: Unfortunately, using events leaves me with a different problem in that it would require getting rid of any loops as well and I feel that would end up just as complicated as having a mess of callbacks. Ideally, I would like an answer as to why there are readSync, writeSync methods for reading and writing to files but there do not exist methods like that for reading from stdin.

Comment: I think Events are made for stuff like this only.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/prompt

Comment: So tried prompt, but unfortunately it does not block. I ended up using wait.for + prompt and that seemed to do the trick. However, it seems overly complicated for such a simple procedure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just found this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync

Example code (after doing an `npm install readline-sync`)

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
while(true) {
  var yn = readlineSync.question("Do you like having tools that let you code how you want, rather than how their authors wanted?");
  if(yn === 'y') {
    console.log("Hooray!");
  } else {
    console.log("Back to callback world, I guess...");
    process.exit();
  }
}
```

Only problem so far is the wailing of the "That's not how node is meant to be used!" chorus, but I have earplugs :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a really big problem here. All background execution (promises running in a loop) seems to be halted by this library. I realize having a bulletproof solution for this not an easy thing to accomplish in node, but I feel that without tackling that specific problem, I don't see the point of it being a dependency.

Comment: So I asked this question about 6 years ago now, but this is the answer i was looking for then, so I am marking your answer as the correct one :D

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the comment about moving towards an event based system and would ditch the loops. I've thrown together a quick example of text based processing which can be used for simple text games.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    es = require('event-stream');

process.stdin
    .pipe(es.split())
    .on('data', parseCommand);

var actionHandlers = {};

function parseCommand(command) {
    var words = command.split(' '),
        action = '';

    if(words.length > 1) {
        action = words.shift();
    }

    if(actionHandlers[action]) {
        actionHandlers[action](words);
    } else {
        invalidAction(action);
    }
}

function invalidAction(action) {
    console.log('Unknown Action:', action);
}

actionHandlers['move'] = function(words) {
    console.log('You move', words);
}

actionHandlers['attack'] = function(words) {
    console.log('You attack', words);
}
```

You can now break up your actions into discrete functions which you can register with a central actionHandlers variable. This makes adding new commands almost trivial. If you can add some details on why the above approach wouldn't work well for you, let me know and I'll revise the answer.

Comment: Okay I actually understand how the event handlers could work and that makes sense and is well written. However it still doesn't answer the core question as to why there are read and write sync methods that are available for files but not for stdin. And then I would still want to know how one could write a sync method for reading from stdin. Like how does fs.readSync work?

Comment: Files have a finite size. You know when you are done reading a file. stdin isn't done until the application closes, at which time it's too late to do anything with the data.

Comment: So then the argument is that since a file is finite, but stdin exists for the duration of the program and has no EOG, then waiting indefinitely for stdin would cause issues. However, I would still argue that since other languages have ability to read from stdin in a blocking fashion so should Node.js (e.g. cin).

Comment: In order to be successful with Node, you'll have to get used to the fact that you have to do things differently than other languages. Sure you could write node very similar to how you would write a PHP application, but then you're crippling your program. There are good reasons why Node is non-blocking and if you try to fight it, you're going to have a bad time. If blocking is critical to you for some reason, as you said, there are other languages that will do what you want.

Comment: Furthermore, my post above shows that you can get the desired results in a non-blocking way without "callback hell". I'm failing to see any reason why you would want to block while waiting for user input other than "other languages let me do it".

Comment: Your example is really good and I can see how it would work. My problem was that actually I had a double-nested while loop. While loop (1) loops through turns and while loop (2) loops through the options for each player. It just became frustrating because if I had a blocking method I could save probably hundreds of lines of code and this is just for a fun project on the side to test out a board game idea I don't even plan to distribute. So it really is a matter of "I don't want to have to write that much code!"

Comment: I think you could save more lines of code with my example above. There is no reason to loop through the available options when you could just register a callback and look up the correct function based on the command. There is actually *less* nesting using the method above than using two loops.

Comment: Yeah it is quite possible that I could save more lines of code using a callback approach. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

ArtHare's solution, at least for my use case, blocks background execution, including those started by a promise. While this code isn't elegant, it did block execution of the current function, until the read from stdin completed.

While this code must run from inside an async function, keep in mind that running an async function from a top-level context (directly from a script, not contained within any other function) will **block** that function until it completes.

Below is a full .js script demonstrating usage, tested with node v8.12.0:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));

async function blockReadLine() {

    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });

    let result = undefined;
    rl.on('line', function(line){
        result = line;
    })

    while(!result) await sleep(100);

    return result;
}

async function run() {
    new Promise(async () => {
        while(true) {
            console.log("Won't be silenced! Won't be censored!");
            await sleep(1000);
        }
    });

    let result = await blockReadLine();
    console.log("The result was:" + result);
    process.exit(0);
}

run();
```